# php files listing with shell_exec

Tags: php, shell, media-player

I've made small script to list all files frome same directory where the script is, and it's listing files as a link.
The questions is how can i change this script to list all files as is, but adding shell_exec to each listed file to play the file in consol ( mp3 files ).

```
<?php

$elementyKatalogu = scandir('.');

$pliki = array();

foreach($elementyKatalogu as $element)
{
    if(is_file($element))
    {
        $pliki[] = $element;
    }
}

echo '<ul>';
foreach($pliki as $plik)
{
    echo '<li>';
    echo '<a href="';
    echo $plik;
    echo '">';
    echo $plik;
    echo '</a>';
    echo '</li>';
}
echo '</ul>';
?>
```

I want to include in this code something like this

```
shell_exec ('mpc play $plik');
```

to every listed file to run it on click. is i possible in some easy way ?

Thank You in advance.

Comment: link then to your player script that takes the file name from the url

Comment: example please, because I've try in many diferent ways and it doesn't work for me ...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

firstly change the links to a local script:

```
echo '<a href="play.php?file='.$plik.'">'.$plik.'</a>';
```

then create play.php

```
$file=$_GET['file'];
shell_exec ('mpc play '.$file);
```

Comment: Thank You it looks good but all i get is 

'$file=$_GET['file']; shell_exec ('mpc play '.$file);'

and nothing is played.

Comment: i did not think i would need to add the `<?php` for you

Comment: Sorry my fault, forgot php tags, but still no effect it doesn't play . PLease any more ideas ?